# Java, HttpURLConnection, залогиниться вк без VK API

Tags: java, вконтакте, httpurlconnection

Здравствуйте. Как можно залогиниться вк при помощи HttpUrlConnection? Про VK API знаю, но в моей ситуации его использовать не вариант

Comment: А какая у вас ситуация? Хакинг? Взлом? Спам?

Comment: Что же у вас за ситуация?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ни в коем случае не спам, мне необходимо вытащить html форму, которая доступна только для авторизованных пользователей

Comment: Так а что мешает авторизироваться через апи и потом тянуть форму???

Comment: авторизация через апи вроде дает только токен, позволяющий вызывать методы api, а  мне нужна прямая авторизация

Comment: Думаю, вряд ли получится корректно сформировать HTTP-запрос к серверу ВК. Тут либо использовать API, либо встраивать в приложение браузер (я использовал Awesomium с С# - надо полагать, для Java тоже что-то есть).

Comment: Зачем "прямая авторизация"? Какой токен ? Токен даётся как раз при успешной авторизации. опишите подробно что вам нужно

Comment: @Viktor окей. Есть линк : vk.com/dev/method/audio.search? если вы перейдете по ссылке будучи авторизованным вк, то снизу страницы у вас появится окошко для тестового обращения к методу audio,search. Если пользователь не авторизован, то этого окошка не будет. Моя задача -- создать connection, который либо мог бы либо открыть этот url авторизованным, либо просто хотя бы авторизоваться вк

Comment: Я получил только 404 not found, а что там за окошко что оно реализовывает?

Comment: извиняюсь, вот правильный линк : vk.com/dev/audio.search?

Comment: Тоесть вам нужен сам метод audio.search? Я на три часа вынужден покинуть беседу